# Programatically tell if a view has a model declared, the model type and whether its null

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razorengine

I investigated using an `IAsyncResultFilter` and using it's `OnResultExecutionAsync` method to look at the `context.Result.Model` but unfortunately if the `context.Result.Model` is null there is no way for me to tell if it's null because no model was declared for the view or because even though one was declared it's null because no model was passed to the view.

Since the Razor View get's compiled before it executes it seems that there should be some stage of the render pipeline where that resultant class can be interacted with and where I can perhaps get the info I need from that class?  But how?

How can I programmatically tell if a view has a model declared, what the model type is and whether the model is null for the current rendering of the view?

As Chris Pratt pointed out in the comments, it might help to understand what the motivation for such a question is.  So here is the back story:

Generally speaking the web application I'm working on has two types of views.  1) views that have view models and that are routed to via an attribute based route specified in the controller and 2) views that that do not have a view model declared and which are routed to by a default route which is handled by a default controller which finds the view based on the url path specified in the request.

This approach works great most of the time, but if I have a view that requires a model and I have a typo in the attribute based route or forget to specify it altogether in the related controller, then the default controller will kick in and try to serve that view but with a null model.  This causes the razor page to throw a generic null reference exception and I'd like to enhance that error message so that it gives better info about the situation.  Namely that the view expects a model but the model was null.  So if I could detect the situation I could throw a more detailed exception that would aid in faster problem identification.

Comment: This screams XY problem. What is it that you're *actually* trying to achieve? Why do you think you need this information? What are you trying to do? Perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: Chris, I had to look up XY problem here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  to know what that was.  Made me laugh, I guess you are right.  I will add to my question to explain what the root issue is I'm trying to solve.

Comment: If your view expects a model, but the model is null, why not check that *in your view* and throw a meaningful error at that point?

Comment: @mason - that would of course work, and I started with that approach.  But my web application has hundreds of views and I quickly realized I didn't want to paste the same code into all of them.  I'd like a global solution where that code can be in one place.

Comment: The obvious solution is: do not write views without a model - always pass a model in. Use a base view-model which contains basic information to be displayed on error, all view-models inherit from that.

Comment: @buffjape that wouldn't solve this problem.  The root cause is that the wrong controller is servicing the view and whether it passes no model (my case) or the wrong model (your case) it's a problem I want to throw an exception on which points out the issue.

Comment: if you never pass "no model", that solves part of the problem.

Comment: @buffjape my view has a view specific model which contains lots of properties that are unique to that view.  If the default controller tries to pass some other type of model to the view other than the view's view specific model (which the default controller know nothing about) then the model received by the view will be null.

Comment: well if you say so, I'm sure that's what will happen.